# SQL sub query with complex criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like this:

```
TransId.   LayerNo.  AccountId.   
100.       1.        2.        
100.       2.        3.        
120.       1.        5.        
120.       2.        6.    
120.       3.        12.     
70.        1.        2.
```

I want to find transId(s) where: 
(LayerNo = 1 and (accountId = 2 or 5))
and
(LayerNo = 2 and (accountId = 3 or 6))

And result set would be row no 1,2,3,4.
How could I write query to get the result?
My database is SQL server 2008 r2
Thanks in advance
Nima

Comment: Is there an and in place of an or above?  There's no way you can have LayerNo=1 AND LayerNo=2, no matter what the other values are.

Comment: How can LayerNo be 1 and 2? Do you mean "or LayerNo = 2"?

Comment: Based off the expected resultset, he is looking for TransIDs that have meet **both** conditions but not only 1. Hence the confusion with LayerNo 1 AND 2 vs 1 OR 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT TransId
FROM   your_table
WHERE  ( layerno = 1
         AND accountid IN ( 2, 5 ) )
INTERSECT
SELECT TransId
FROM   your_table
WHERE  ( layerno = 2
         AND accountid IN ( 3, 6 ) )
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to ensure that each transID must have two records that satisfy the conditions you outlined.

```
SELECT * FROM 
TABLE
WHERE TransID IN( 
    SELECT TransId 
    FROM   table 
    WHERE  ( layerno = 1 
             AND  accountid IN ( 2, 5 )  ) 
            OR ( layerno = 2 
                 AND  accountid IN( 3, 6 )  ) 
    GROUP BY 
        TransId
    HAVING Count(*) = 2
    )
```

However this could be a problem if you can have multple records where layerno = 1. So you can use self joins instead to ensure the criteria.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.transid 
FROM   table a 
       INNER JOIN table b 
         ON a.transid = b.transid 
       INNER JOIN table c 
         ON a.transid = c.transid 
WHERE  b.layerno = 1 
       AND accountid IN ( 2, 5 ) 
       AND c.layerno = 2 
       AND accountid IN ( 3, 6 )
```

That said [Martin's INTERSECT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9103799/119477) approach is probably the best

Comment: This will include row 6 in the resultset, which is not desired

Comment: your answer also do the job, but as you said Conrad's solution is much easier and more i have layer(s) to check, more joint should be get involved, which i think would be a performance issue. am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
SELECT 
   TransId,  
   LayerNo,  
   AccountId
FROM Table
WHERE (LayerNo = 1 AND AccountId IN (2, 5)) OR 
      (LayerNo = 2 AND AccountId IN (3, 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #temp

( rowId Int Identity(1,1), transId int)

INSERT INTO #temp(transId)  
select TransId
from TableName
where (layerNo = 1 and accountID IN (2, 5))
OR (layerNo = 2 and accountId IN (3, 6))
select * from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   base.TransId,  
   base.LayerNo,  
   base.AccountId
FROM TableX AS base
  JOIN TableX AS a
    ON  a.TransId = base.TransId
    AND a.LayerNo = 1 AND a.AccountId IN (2, 5)
  JOIN TableX AS b
    ON  b.TransId = base.TransId
    AND b.LayerNo = 2 AND b.AccountId IN (3, 7)
WHERE (base.LayerNo = 1 AND base.AccountId IN (2, 5)) 
   OR (base.LayerNo = 2 AND base.AccountId IN (3, 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

This intersection is empty. If you take the values where LayerNo = 1 and LayerNo = 2 and intersect them their intersection is empty because these events are mutually exclusive. I believe this error comes from how the question was originally stated. I might be wrong but the predicate should have been
(LayerNo = 1 and (accountId = 2 or 5)) OR (LayerNo = 2 and (accountId = 3 or 6))
Replace the AND with an OR. If the predicate was stated correctly then the intersect is correct but will always be empty.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  table
 WHERE  (LayerNo = 1 AND (AccountID = 2 OR AccountID = 5))
   OR   (LayerNo = 2 AND (AccountID = 3 OR AccountID = 6))
```

Comment: He wants only transids that have a row that meets both conditions.  This only checks single rows.